# Linking a Google account (oauth2) spring security

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring rest web application where I am doing authentication with a single game token. I would like to add Google (or GitHub, Facebook, Telegram) account binding (oauth2) so that I can log in with oauth2, because it takes a long time to generate a token every time, how can this be implemented?

My code https://github.com/iNiceHero/VueAuthSpring

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/", "/api/auth/**", "/js/**", "/error**", "/login", "/api/user/**").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and().csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation().migrateSession();

    }

}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));
        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsImpl.java**

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserDetailsImpl(
                user.getId(),
                user.getUsername(),
                authorities);
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return null;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }
}
```

**AuthController.java authenticateUser**

```
 if (!userRepository.existsByUsername(username)) {
        User user;
        if (userRepository.existsById(id)) {
            user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
            user.setUsername(username);
        } else {
            user = new User(username, id);
        }
        Set<String> strRoles = loginRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);
                        break;
                    case "mod":
                        Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(modRole);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails1 = UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails1, null, userDetails1.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
  
    List<String> rolesUser = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new UserResponse(
            userDetails.getId(),
            userDetails.getUsername(),
            rolesUser));
```